# vb.net color first char in cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors, char

In VB .NET I have 3 characters which are added to a DataGridView cell depending on some calculations.

They are rank change arrows and work fine, but I want the up arrow to be green and the down arrow to be red.

```
Dim strup As String = "▲"
Dim strdown As String = "▼"
Dim strsame As String = "▬"
```

So in the cell a change of negative three will look like ▼3 and plus 3 will look like ▲3 where the text and symbol are different colors.

How can I change the color of the first character in DataGridView cell?

Comment: are we talking about WPF or WinForms?

Comment: I think its not possible to only make that char red or green I think you have to set the .forecolor of the cell

Comment: seems like a dead end...

Comment: you can always try the draw event and draw the char yourself

Comment: tbh I should gave up or change the color of the whole cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this if you have anything more than just the character in question in the cell (you would need to do some form of custom painting).

If you only have those characters then this is very easy with the CellFormatting event:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    e.CellStyle.Font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 12);
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CorrectColumnName")
    {
        if (e.Value == "▲")
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        else if (e.Value == "▼")
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        else
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

---

If you do want different colors within the same cell then something like the following code is required (this handles the CellPainting event):

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 || e.RowIndex == -1)
        return;

    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CorrectColumnName")
    {
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);

        if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().StartsWith("▲", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            RenderCellText(Color.Green, e);
        }
        else if (e.FormattedValue == "▼")
        {
            RenderCellText(Color.Red, e);
        }
        else
            RenderCellText(SystemColors.WindowText, e);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void RenderCellText(Color color, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    string text = e.FormattedValue.ToString();
    string beginning = text.Substring(0, 1);
    string end = text.Substring(1);
    Point topLeft = new Point(e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height / 4));

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, beginning, this.dataGridView1.Font, topLeft, color);
    Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(beginning, this.dataGridView1.Font);

    Point p = new Point(topLeft.X + s.Width, topLeft.Y);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, end, this.dataGridView1.Font, p, SystemColors.WindowText);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to prototype a custom painting code now - also if you can't translate this into VB.Net yourself I can provide that code. It isn't my first language so I gave the c# that I can code from memory.

Comment: but what about the rank number will it stay black?

Comment: @user1570048 What do you mean rank number? Is there text within the same cell as your up and down arrows? Then you will need something like my second option (and again, if you really need it I can work through a VB.Net example)

Comment: c# is fine will convert to vb and tell you what happenes

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once and ended up putting these characters in their own column.