# Different font colors in same DataGridView cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there a way to use 2 different colors in the same cell in a `DataGridView`? I am using vb.net 2010.

Comment: what kind of colors? Text color, background color, etc..

Comment: font color, one line black and the second line red

Comment: Sounds like the question here is aiming for something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828281/vb-net-color-first-char-in-cell/11828960#11828960

Comment: My answer to that was in c# but if it looks like it works and you need vb.net I can provide the converted code.

Answer (score 0):

Put code in the DataGridView.CellFormatting Event

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
    Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
    ' If the column is the Artist column, check the 
    ' value. 
    If Me.dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name _
        = "Artist" Then 
        If e.Value IsNot Nothing Then 

            ' Check for the string "pink" in the cell. 
            Dim stringValue As String = _
            CType(e.Value, String)
            stringValue = stringValue.ToLower()
            If ((stringValue.IndexOf("pink") > -1)) Then
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink
            End If 

        End If 
    ElseIf Me.dataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name _
        = "Release Date" Then
        ShortFormDateFormat(e)
    End If 
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx

Comment: I will try this and comment. Thank's